# How to get Datatable Unique Constraint Exception values in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a UniqueConstraint setup for two columns of my datatable.

```
dtContacts.Constraints.Add(new UniqueConstraint(new DataColumn[] 
{ 
  dtContacts.Columns["Last Name"], 
  dtContacts.Columns["First Name"] ]
}
));
```

So when ConstraintException occurs, I get a message like this:

> "Column 'Last Name, First Name' is constrained to be unique. Value
>   'Grant, Alex' is already present"

Generated by pretty standard code:

```
MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
```

Is there any way to get specifically values that triggered the exception? I need to get 'Grant, Alex' so I can string build a custom message.

Comment: If you first turn off constraint and perform your actions and then turn on constraints, yes, you can get more information.

Comment: Are you saying, you do not want `"Column 'Last Name, First Name' is constrained to be unique. Value` at all, but only the `'Grant, Alex'``?

Comment: Reza Aghaei - sorry I did not get, could you please be more specific?

Comment: Ian - I just basically want to extract this particular information out of exception message. So yes, I need data (in my case Last Name and First Name) that triggered the exception.